# Is there a more general word than "type" or "kind" or "style" that fits these sentences?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a particular word that satisfies the below sentences?

> Low sodium is a ____ of soy sauce.
>
> Extra strength is a ____ of medicine.
>
> Hatchback is a ____ of vehicle.
>
> Steel-toe is a ____ of boot.
>
> Rechargable is a ____ of flashlight.

I think it's something like "type" or "kind" or "style" but it doesn't sound right using each one for each example.  Is there possibly a word that contains all these words as "subsets"?  (Like all frogs are amphibians)

Comment: If a generic term like *type*, etc., is not to your taste, you may choose according to context. How can one word fit different situations and still be not generic? Consider as needed: ": sort, variety, class, category, genre, genus, species, family, order, breed, race, strain, design, form, pattern, brand, make, model, line, ...." Good Luck.

Comment: There are many applicable terms *(class, grade, category,...)* - many of which would suit *some* of your exact contexts better than others, so there's no single unambiguously correct answer. The question is thus POB.

Comment: I'm not sure what "Extra strength is a ____ of medicine" means. Does this mean some medicines give you extra strength, or some medicines are described as extra strength (by containing more of the active ingredient, for example)? I guess "Low sodium is a ___ of soy sauce" means "some soy sauce is low sodium" or "low sodium soy sauce is a type of soy sauce", but it's not entirely clear either. But if the word "type" doesn't seem to fit, that might be because the examples are garbled or hard to parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say

- "low sodium is a **variety** of soy sauce"
- "hatchback is a car **model**"
- "extra-strength is a dosage **form** of Tylenol"
- "rechargeable is a **category** of flashlight"
- "steel-toe is a **type** of boot".

But I can't think of any single word - other than type or kind - that fits all your sentences perfectly.

Comment: I think variety/varietal would work OK for most of those.